# boost python boost:shared_ptr to boost::any convertible

Tags: python, c++, boost, type-conversion

I am new to the boost python framework. After following some example code in the internet, I am reaching the following situation: I use a static member function to create a shared_ptr of the object of class C and use another static function to visit the shared_ptr to the object of class C, that works fine. However, in some situation, I need boost::any as argument for the visit function e.g. visitAny in the code, then I will check if the boost::any is the required type. I am now missing the conversion function to convert the boost::shared_ptr to boost::any before I am calling the visitAny function, could anyone kindly point out where and how should I implement the conversion function.

Thank you in advance.

```
class C {
public:
    C() : member_(0) {};
    static boost::shared_ptr<C> create();
    static int visit(boost::shared_ptr<C>& c);
    static int C::visitAny(boost::shared_ptr<boost::any>& c);
    int member_;
};

boost::shared_ptr<C> C::create() {
    return boost::shared_ptr<C>(new C());
}

int C::visit(boost::shared_ptr<C>& c) {
    return c->member_;
}

int C::visitAny(boost::shared_ptr<boost::any>& c) {
    if (c->type() == typeid(boost::shared_ptr<C>))
        return boost::any_cast<boost::shared_ptr<C>>(c)->member_;
    else
        return 100;
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(boostPythonTest)
{

    class_<C, boost::shared_ptr<C>, boost::noncopyable>("C", boost::python::no_init)
        .def("create", &C::create)
        .staticmethod("create")
        .def("visit", &C::visit)
        .staticmethod("visit")
        .def("visitAny", &C::visitAny)
        .staticmethod("visitAny");

}
```

Comment: resolved by using boost::python::extract<T>()

Comment: Can you, please, clarify how you use this construct `boost::python::extract<T>() ` ?